# multiple collections in one admin grid?

Tags: adminhtml, collection, grid

Is it possible to have multiple collections in one grid? Suppose if we have grouped data, and we need to display it in multiple dynamic child grids.

Suppose data is:

```
firstname lastname city
Group 1: 
mark      james     new york
mark      james     new york

Group 2:
mark      james     california
mark      james     california

Group 3 :
aston    wright     france
aston    liam       france
```

Is it possible?

Comment: os is it possible to pass parameter(collection) in controller and looping the admin grid to get multiple grids on same page?

Comment: How do you group the collection? It is loaded from one table? If collection items is loaded from one table and you want to display them as grouped visually, it is not too hard task. Please, clarify your situation more.

Comment: Thanks mageUz. please check this code$collections =Mage::getSingleton('mergeaccount/data')->getGroups();$collection_of_things = new Varien_Data_Collection();foreach($collections as $collection) {$collection_of_things->addItem($collection);}$this->setCollection($collection_o‌​f_things);return parent::_prepareCollection(); where $collections is array of Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter($attribut‌​enames[0], array('eq'=>$arrrayData[$k][$attributenames[0]]));

Comment: Above code gives me error "it gives error "Fatal error: Call to a member function append() on a non-object". Please let me know where am i going wrong? Thanks again :)

Answer (score 4):

You may add several grids to the page.

Otherwise you will need to create some sort of compound collection in _prepareCollection method. In this case, you'd better create some new model which would be dealing with data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you please explain little more. i used this code but it did not work ( i used loop to set collections)                                                               $collections =Mage::getSingleton('mergeaccount/data')->getGroups(); 
  
  foreach($collections as $collection) {
   $this->setCollection($collection);
  }
  
       return parent::_prepareCollection(); Could you please paste code for compound collection? and also is it possible to pass parameters from controller and iterate grid block in controller?  Thanks in advance:)

Comment: could someone explain it little more? if possible with an exmaple. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: In your example _$this->setCollection($collection)_ will use only data from last one. You need to combine them though. If your data are in different tables you will probably need to add them into _Varien_Data_Collection_ object with _addItem_. Item to be added is _Varien_Object_. So you do `$item = new Varien_Object()`, then `$item->addData($arr)` and `$varienCollection->addItem($item)`.
Something like this. That all should be done in you model, where you take your data from various sources and create new collection.

Comment: [this link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-8-varien-data-collections) may help.

Comment: Thanks again for the answer. i used this code.   $collections =Mage::getSingleton('mergeaccount/data')->getGroups();$collection_of_things = new Varien_Data_Collection();foreach($collections as $collection) {$collection_of_things->addItem($collection);}$this->setCollection($collection_of_things);return parent::_prepareCollection(); where $collections is array of Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter($attributenames[0], array('eq'=>$arrrayData[$k][$attributenames[0]]));

Comment: Above code gives me error "it gives error "Fatal error: Call to a member function append() on a non-object". Please let me know where am i going wrong? Thanks again :)

Comment: i am still looking for answer. :(. i will really appreciate it if someone can explain it more. thanks :)

Comment: If I got you right `$collections = Mage::getSingleton('mergeaccount/data')->getGroups()` returns several collections. Then you must walk through them and add all items to the new one. Like this: `foreach($collections as $collection) { foreach($collection as $item) { $collection_of_things->addItem($item); } }`. You must be sure all items has the same fields.

Comment: Thank you very much Taras. I have used the loop, but it is giving error. Fatal error: Call to a member function append() on a non-object in D:\wamp\www\projects\magmergeacc\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Controller\Action.php on line 122. could you please guide me on this. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: secondly, i think $collection_of_things will display one grid, rather than each collection as separate grid/block? though each collection has same attributes. please guide me on this as well. thanks again :)

Comment: Taras, i used same loop, but it gave me error. Fatal error: Call to a member function append() on a non-object in D:\wamp\www\projects\magmergeacc\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Controller\Action.‌​php on line 122. could you please guide me on this. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: yes, if you use something like I posted above _$collection_of_things_ will have collection for one grid. I you need several different, then you need a bit other approach. You may add more grids through layout. As for your error, you need to check how your module adds grid (use for reference some tutorial like [this](http://www.pierrefay.com/magento-admin-gridview-85). Creating own collection from different data sources, you should make them using same keys in array: `$item->addData(array('id'=>$d1,'name'=>$d2,'addr'=>$d3))` for all the data.

Comment: It's a bit to hard to make suggestions abstractly and create full working example is time consuming. 't would be better if you provide your code for discussion :)

Comment: Taras thanks a lot for taking your time for it. i really appreciate it. thanks :)

Comment: Basically i cannot use layout because grid that i want to display should be dynamic, but they have same attributes.

Comment: Suppose this is array of collections: for( $k =0; $k<count($arrrayData); $k++ ) {$collectionGroup[] = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter($attributenames[0], array('eq'=>$arrrayData[$k][$attributenames[0]]))->addFieldToFilter($attributenames[1], array('eq'=>$arrrayData[$k][$attributenames[1]])) ->addFieldToFilter($attributenames[2], array('eq'=>$arrrayData[$k][$attributenames[2]]))
    ; 
} now i need to display each array element as different grid on same page. please guide me on this. i am really thankful to you:)